# Minimum number of different clues in a Sudoku

Tags: computational-complexity, propositional-calculus

I wonder if there are proper $9\times9$ Sudokus having $7$ or less different clues. I know that $17$ is the minimum number of clues. In most Sudokus there are $1$ to $4$ clues of every number. Sometimes I found a Sudoku with only $8$ different clues. 
[image]

In this example the number $9$ is missing, but the Sudoku was very well solvable. 
Is it possible to have a $9\times9$ Sudoku with less than $8$ different clues?

Comment: Have you seen [Mathematicians Solve Minimum Sudoku Problem](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/426554/mathematicians-solve-minimum-sudoku-problem/) ?

Comment: must resist urge to solve sudoku...

Comment: The Discord Server for Cracking the Cryptic (https://discord.com/channels/709370620642852885/709380623399256104) has a "theory and programming" thread where various geniuses (including Philip Newman of the 18 cells in killer cages "White Room" [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejhtYYvUs5M ] puzzle - a minimum for killer cages) discuss and test ideas about minimum numbers of different kinds of clues associated with variants of Sudoku. There is a lot on there which does not get on Wikipedia because it is personal research.

Answer (score 34):

If I understand you correctly the answer is no. If the only numbers in the initial grid are $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ then in any solution you will be able to swap $8$ and $9$ and you will still have a valid solution.

Comment: In case of any confusion, it should also be said that it is a stated rule of Sudoku that puzzles have a single, unique solution.

Comment: We need more concise but informative proofs like this one.

Comment: @AnonymousPi That would be lovely but many interesting problems don't admit such proofs: "Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler." (attributed to Einstein)

Answer (score 0):

Does the mere interchangeability of 2 or more missing values really result in more than one solution?

In a standard sudoku these 'values' are only symbols and bear no arithmetical value or meaning. Follow the reasoning above and not any standard sudoku with even 8 different clues can have a unique solution, because you are free to fill in the 9 free cells with any individual number (or icon of clover, pet animal or ladybug).

I think, that as long

1. as the 8, 7 or less given symbols allow only one result among them
   (and with enough givens they will) and if
2. the remaining available cells can be filled in only one way to accommodate any 1, 2 or more different arbitrary symbols

that ought to be regarded as a unique solution and thus, the puzzle in question as well-posed.
I am not entirely sure if this is possible to construct, but think it's rather likely.
Thank you for taking up this interesting question.

edit:
As an example, I took the unique solution to a trivial standard sudoku, removed 2 of the symbols and searched for the ways to share the free cells.

A puzzle with only 7 different values given:

```
-------------------------
| 1 4 7 | 2   8 | 3 6   |
| 2   8 | 3 6   | 4 7 1 |
| 3 6   | 4 7 1 |   8 2 |
-------------------------
| 4 7 1 |   8 2 | 6   3 |
|   8 2 | 6   3 | 7 1 4 |
| 6   3 | 7 1 4 | 8 2   |
-------------------------
| 7 1 4 | 8 2   |   3 6 |
| 8 2   |   3 6 | 1 4 7 |
|   3 6 | 1 4 7 | 2   8 |
-------------------------
```

And the only possible distribution of the missing values (named arbitrarily):

```
-------------------------    -------------------------
|       |       |     A |    |       |   B   |       |
|       |     A |       |    |   B   |       |       |
|     A |       |       |    |       |       | B     |
-------------------------    -------------------------
|       |       |   A   |    |       | B     |       |
|       |   A   |       |    | B     |       |       |
|   A   |       |       |    |       |       |     B |
-------------------------    -------------------------
|       |       | A     |    |       |     B |       |
|       | A     |       |    |     B |       |       |
| A     |       |       |    |       |       |   B   |
-------------------------    -------------------------
```

Every symbol in a standard sudoku's solution is placed according to one out of 46656 distribution patterns.

My understanding of a 'unique solution' could be expressed like:
There exists exactly one set of 9 patterns that can be combined without overlapping and where each pattern covers one of the (given or missing) symbols.

Returning to the OP's question, my answer would be 'yes', sudoku puzzles may have less than 8 different values given and still result in a unique solution.

Which brings up some other questions to be maybe explored in the future:

1. How much further can the number of different values be decreased?
2. How much could an individual value's count be decreased?
3. And how are these parameters related?

I really wouldn't know how to find proof in any form.

Comment: That's not the usual way Sudoku folks look at solution uniqueness, but it is an interesting one! It looks like most grids allow puzzles that can satisfy your definition with clues using just 6 distinct digits. And there are some grids where it's possible with just 5. Here is an example of a puzzle on such a grid: 
`1...2...3.4.............21....2...3..2....5..5...13.4..1..34...3...5....2.......5`
This has 24 conventional solutions, but just one based the patterns you describe above. Not sure if it's possible with just 4. Probably not.

Comment: @53x15: That's fascinating! Thank you for sharing.
I've come to think of naming groups and clues by arbitrary numbers as a mere convenience method and not as any immanent, defining part of the puzzle.
If the values of a sudoku were swapped, I wouldn't think of it as being a different puzzle and the same applies to any solution.
Do you think (or even happen to know) if the number of 17 minimal clues could also be subject to a change of view on solution uniqueness?